# The code flow jumps without getting into any of the if-block

Tags: ide, flashdevelop

I edited this question, as now it seems it's not a coding issue. Might be something with IDE or something else.
I am using Flash Develop 4.5.2 right now.

I added a small check in the class, to test equality. But it's showing strange result. 
A 1 min video on Youtube about the problem => http://youtu.be/wHXs7nwyhow

![The flow jumps without getting any of the if-block][1]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD3YM.png
```

Might be some special characters issue. So, pasted it on notepad, and saved it back as ".as", but still that part is skipped by debugger. No matter, whatever i write there. ( See video )

Vishwas

Comment: Is it going inside `getTransitionByName` & throwing an error?

Comment: It's going inside, and when i check values in debugger they show exactly equal. That is to say, they should go in "equal" block. 
However, i am now having a feeling, that it is something to do with the debugger. Downloading the latest update of Flash Develop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug. I checked OFF "Omit trace actions" in Flash IDE ( So as to receive the trace statements in the trace window now ). And it's working fine now. ( It seems like Flash Develop debugger, tries ignoring those pieces of code, that are related with trace() in such case.